# AWS sam local create infrastructure locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, localstack

I'm working with a lambda function and it will be receiving events from kinesis and after processing them, they could be sent to sns, s3, etc.

I want to make possible to test it locally so I wonder how I could create the infrastructure (function lambda, sqs, sns, s3, etc) locally.

I was checking sam local but not sure if it possible to create all the components mentioned previously with cloudformation. I only saw some examples and all of them show how to send an event to be processed by the lambda but any of them show a way to create the infrastructure with cloudformation locally.

Not 100% sure, but I think it's not possible to do it with "sam local".

The other option is to do it with localstack and create the infra with terraform. Basically I'd like to confirm with you if it possible to do it with "sam local" as this is the official tool provided. Thanks